# Writing to /var/log/auth.log

Tags: log, logging

We'd like an application to write entries to /var/log/auth.log
Is there any kind of interface to allow us to do this?
thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Following command is exactly what you need:

```
logger -p auth.info "Log message"
```

I specified the severity level as info which is identified as lower severity but you can change the severity to whatever you want. Possible values for severity are as follows:

```
1-Alert
2-Critical
3-Error
4-Warning
5-Notice
6-Info
7-Debug
```

The further down you go in the list, severity level decreases accordingly